# How to integrate remita in laravel application?

Tags: laravel, api, integration, payment

How to Integrate API remita in laravel? I want to do api integration remita in laravel for my project. Please anyone say some good ideas. I am tried to implementation https://github.com/femonofsky/remita-laravel, but I am failed.

`$ "femonofsky/remita": "~1.0"`

I used in Laravel 6.2.8.

Comment: I am tried to implementation https://github.com/femonofsky/remita-laravel. This Package helps with the Integration of Remita Payment Gateway and Laravel

Comment: After adding `"femonofsky/remita": "~1.0"` in the `composer.json` file (under the section `require`) you have to run the command `composer update` in the root of the project folder